# toggle on hover and click not working properly

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

I've created this little toggle, since i"m starting with javascript, but it's not working as I would like to. The  brown box should appear and disappear both on hover and click (for ipad mostly).

Right now it's fine for hover, but not for  clicking on ipad, it just appears once, and thats it.

I think it's also getting confused with my sharing icons.

Any help is appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69hexmb0/11/)

```js
function toggleDisplay (toBlock, toNone) {
    document.getElementById(toBlock).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(toNone).style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#toggle_hero
{
 float:left;
}
.leftHalf
{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.leftHalf div
{
    display:none;
}
.leftHalf:hover
{
}

.leftHalf:hover div
{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 23%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 70px;
    right: 0;
    background: white;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:rgba(207,167,80,0.7);
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: 200;
}

.leftHalf:hover div h3
{
    font-weight: 500;
    float:left;
}
.leftHalf:hover div span{
    float:right;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
hover (on a pc) or click me (on ipad)    
<div id="toggle_hero" onclick="toggleDisplay('comment', 'toggle_hero')">
        <div class="leftHalf clearfix" id="comment">
           <div>
               <span>
                <a target="_blank" class="icon-facebook fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'facebook-share','width=580,height=296');return false;">facebook </a>&nbsp;
                   

                <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://google.com" class="fa fa-twitter"> twitter</a>
              </span>
              <h3>this text should appear both on hover and click (for ipad)</h3> 
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an event listener that captures the current toggled state in a var.

```
var toggle = false;

var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (toggle === false) {
        this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.display = 'none';
        toggle = true;
    } else {
        this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.display = 'initial';
        toggle = false;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/bLkdt6mc/

You can add another listener for the 'mouseover'.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is a bit weird. The text that you want to hover/click is actually outside of the target area for your click event. It happens to work for me locally because of the absolute positioning, but I wouldn't be surprised if the iPad browser behaves differently.

I would suggest defining a clear target for what is to be clicked/hovered, apply a class on click/hover, and handle the rest in CSS. I put together a sample of what I envision. You can remove the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to simulate on a computer how it works with the touch events. I'm not sure exactly how you want it to behave, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

```js
function setHover(isHover) {
 var element = document.getElementById("toggle_hero");
 if (isHover)
  element.className = "hovered";
 else
  element.className = "";
}

function toggleHover() {
 var element = document.getElementById("toggle_hero");
 setHover(element.className === "");
}
```

```css
#toggle_hero {
 float:left;
}

#comment {
 display:none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 23%;
 overflow: auto;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: white;
 color: #fff;
 background-color:rgba(207,167,80,0.7);
 padding:10px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 font-weight: 200;
}

.hovered #comment {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle_hero" onclick="toggleHover()" onmouseenter="setHover(true);" onmouseleave="setHover(false);">
 hover (on a pc) or click me (on ipad)  
 <div id="comment">
  <div>
     <span>
   <a target="_blank" class="icon-facebook fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'facebook-share','width=580,height=296');return false;">facebook </a>&nbsp;
   <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://google.com" class="fa fa-twitter"> twitter</a>
    </span>
    <h3>this text should appear both on hover and click (for ipad)</h3> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```